# Good ereader for hand-written notes

Tags: pdf, e-ink, djvu

I need an e-ink screen I can look at all day without getting my eyes sore (no more than I would on a book, at least). I need it to study, so I'm about to read PDFs and DJVUs, consisting of scanned books, lecture notes taken from a tactile screen with software like OneNote, and also lecture notes hand-written on plain paper and then scanned to file.

I wanted to ask you if there is a good device which can handle those tasks decently. The features I'm looking for are:

- Good rendering of scanned and handwritten PDFs and DJVUs
- Bearable loading times
- Software open enough to switch to alternative reading apps if the built-in one does not satisfy me

I don't particularly need good backlight (even if every ereader now has it) or touch screen (idem). I say this because I'll be reading mostly under the sun, so what I really need is a good contrast which will allow me to read perfectly using natural (even intense) light, like a real book. I've read capacitive layers can negatively affect this.

Also, I've heard to have a good rendition of PDFs you have to get close to natural size of the page. But I've seen big screens tend to have a much lower resolution than small screens. Is it just to limit manufacture costs? Isn't a good resolution more important?

Note: I know similar questions have already been asked, but I didn't find any really satisfying answer. In the meantime technology went forward, so I'm asking what the options are in 2016.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What devices support reading scanned PDF documents well?](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/what-devices-support-reading-scanned-pdf-documents-well)

Comment: my questions: How much is your badget? Do you care about portability? min dimension of device you prefer?